# getIdentifier() from a textView returns null

Tags: java, android, textview, android-cardview, android-identifiers

I'm trying to get different ID with `for`. What I have is a CardView with diferent IDs for each card and I would like to get data when clicked.

I have done this:

```
 public void setToggleEvent(final GridLayout mainGrid) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++){

        count = i;

        final CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(i);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {

                    for (int f = 0; f < mainGrid.getChildCount(); f++){

                        if (f == count) {
                            int index = f;

                            String idFood = "food" + index;
                            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(idFood, "id", getPackageName());

                            foodName =  findViewById(resID);
                            foodName.getText();
                        }

                    }

                    //canvi color de fons
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));


                    foodData = foodName.toString();
                   selectedVegetables.add(foodData);


                } else {

                    cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    Toast.makeText(VegetablesActivity.this, "Food Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

        });

    }
}
```

Each card has a ID called: food0, food1, food2....

As you can see in the code I did this to get the IDs:

```
String idFood = "food" + index;
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(idFood, "id", getPackageName());
foodName =  findViewById(resID);
foodName.getText();
```

and then:

```
foodData = foodName.toString();
selectedVegetables.add(foodData);
```

But when I run it says that `foodName` is null ( `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference`)

and is in this line where the error shows up

```
foodName.getText();
```

Any idea? 
 Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native lenguage, hope everyone could understand this.

Answer (score -1):

I surprised! this is not actually logical!

```
foodName =  findViewById(resID);
```

`int resID` not provide you like this: "R.id.exampleId" type of id.

**resID** Only provide you a integer value.